# Why can't the compiler warn against this programming error?

Tags: java, if-statement

If I write the following code:

```
int a = 5;
if (a == 1 || a == 1) {
   // do something
}
```

Why can't the compiler point out that the second part of the if statement is unnecessary, or warn that the programmer has likely made a mistake?

Comment: Why would it? There is no error here.

Comment: Also, it's not the compiler's job. You have linters and other code quality tools to decide that "the programmer probably made a typo". Compiler makes things work as coded.

Comment: your IDE or some code analysis tool might tell you that it's unreachable code

Comment: In fact compiler will wanr you. And in the same time compiler will apply "dead code illumination" i.e. removes whole if statement from byte-code binary, since this `if` will never invoked because `a` is a constant and eq 5.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I see - you are right. Is it worth closing this question?

Comment: Yes. It certainly is.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler does not do it. But the IDE might detect the underlying problem. For example:

[image]